# Prevent login loop

Tags: greeter

I recently faced the famous login loop in ubuntu 18 and I tried everything to fix it yet I was not able to do so, since i was just getting started with ubuntu and i had nothing on it I decided to completely uninstall it.

Yesterday tho, I installed ubuntu 18.04 again but with a twist, I installed the elementary OS which seemed easier, and more stable (and for me, it is!!), but now I'm thinking, hey, what if i run into the same problem again!, i really tried everything to fix it and i have no idea what did i do to run into the problem in the first place.

So my question is, Is there any tips or advises to avoid the login loop?.

PD: some of my PC specifications (its a "gaming laptop"):

```
Geforce GTX 1050 (Nvidia)
intel i5 CPU
8GB RAM 
1TB space on hard disk (i have assigned 150GB for ubuntu (elementary OS))
```

PD2: yes, i have installed all of the drivers that nvidia needs

Answer (score 0):

If you did not get the login boot loop after you did the eos install i dont think you need to worry, just sit back and enjoy the elementary journey.

Comment: It happened again, so funny haha, I uninstall it all and at the end decided to go along with a virtual machine